# Calculating borders of a rectangle

Tags: coordinates

My question is a bit of definition related.

Let's say we have got a rectangle with its top-left corner at (0,0) and width=100px height=200px. My question is: how we compute the *last* pixels that *belong* to the rectangle? Specifically I want to know the x coords of the left and right border and y coords of top and bottom border that contains pixels belonging to the rectangle.

I tried to simply `left=origin x`, `right=origin x + width`, `top=origin y`, `bottom=origin y - height`, but during tests I found out that when rectangles are next to each other the above equations results in pixels that belongs to more than one rectangle at once (they shouldn't). So, I wish to know how to calculate them *properly*.

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre], also please tag which language/environment you are using - [ask]

Comment: Well, I'm asking about a definition. It is not related directly to any environment or language.

Comment: Clarify the definition of the units of {width,height}.
If it is [pixel], right will be `left + width - 1`. (where, units of {left, right} is [pixel] too) Thinking about `width=1`, right and left should be same in this definition.

Comment: SO is meant for programming-related issues. Consider researching your question on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll but I thought to ask also about how calculating pixels is done in the programmers world too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this figure,

- Orange rect : (left,top) = (1,2), width=3, height=2
- Green rect : (left,top) = (4,3), width=2, height=2

I think, this is the ordinal definition for pixel world.

In this example, no pixels belong to both.